# Sublimetext3 (javascript) - Change colour of expressions in template literals

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

So I'm using `Sublime Text 3` text editor since recently and I keep stumbling upon something that I find annoying.. is it possible to have the `${variable}` colour to be the same colour as the strings/template literals in a theme?

```
`The colour of a ${variable} in a template literal is always white regardless of string colour`
```

here's an example of my text editor with the current colours: [current colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/305pa.png)

here's an example of my desired text editor colours (photoshop): [desired colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmzfo.png)

Answer (score 0):

just add that to the colour scheme of sublime

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>STACK DAT DOUGH</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>punctuation.dollar</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#F92672</string> // desired color 
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it wasn't the answer I was looking for, but you definitely put me on the right trail! I've posted an answer of my own :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply @mooga, it wasn't the answer I was looking for, but you definitely put me on the right trail. This answer may not be what I wanted to have as my desired layout but this will make due, see pictures underneath!

[original colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1289j.png)

[desired colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmPYJ.png)

[end result colours (using script below - this image is scuffed but mostly visible)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L3X1.png)

```
{
  "name": "Punctuation",
  "scope": "punctuation.definition",
  "foreground": "var(yellow)"
}
```

For those that read and wish to do this in the future, follow these steps:

1. have sublime open
2. open `Tools` -> select `Command Parelette...` *(before next step, you may have to install `PackageResourceViewer` or something similar using `Command Parelette...` - I cannot remember how I did this before, you'll have to figure this out first)*
3. search and select: `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
4. search and select: `Color Scheme - Default`
5. search and select: `[YOUR_CURRENT_THEME].sublime-color-scheme` *(In my case: `Monokai` = I'm selecting `Monokai.sublime-color-scheme`)*
6. paste the script displayed above into `"rules": []` *([view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWqSL.png))*

More information can be found here: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html#punctuation